# fo file convert to pdf in java

Tags: java, xml, pdf, xslt, apache-fop

I am new to java and fo trying to convert a fo file to pdf I copied java from [this](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlgraphics/fop/trunk/examples/embedding/java/embedding/ExampleFO2PDF.java?view=markup) link, but I am getting the error below:

> Transforming... log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.apache.fop.util.ContentHandlerFactoryRegistry). log4j:WARN Please
>   initialize the log4j system properly. Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/avalon/framework/configuration/ConfigurationException  at
>   org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.(FopFactory.java:165)    at
>   org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newInstance(FopFactory.java:190)   at
>   fop.ExampleFO2PDF.(ExampleFO2PDF.java:73)   at
>   fop.ExampleFO2PDF.main(ExampleFO2PDF.java:156) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.ConfigurationException  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 4 more

Comment: It says Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.ConfigurationException, that means org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.ConfigurationException class is missing in any of the jars, add the same and try again

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Could you please add more details?It seems you have a missing dependency org/apache/avalon/framework/configuration/ConfigurationException

Comment: @abarisone am using a eclipse ide

Comment: @Saurabh Jhunjhunwala ya i searched then i copied jar to workspace then to is show error

Comment: Did you add that jar to the java build path. you need to make sure that the complier refers to that jar. simple pasting the jar does not confirm its usage.

Comment: ya i build correctly path

Comment: The method newInstance() in the type FopFactory is not applicable for the arguments (URI)  am getting this error while i use a code what it mean below                                                                                                  '// configure fopFactory as desired
            final FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(new File(".").toURI());'

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to embed FOP. But you have not added Avalon to the classpath (as some have already suggested), or you have the wrong version. See also:

- [Re: Embedding FOP: error with FopFactory](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xmlgraphics-fop-users/200803.mbox/%3C20080302163521.ADFD.DEV@jeremias-maerki.ch%3E)
- [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=704298#c7) (comment #7), this explains that even if you have the Avalon framework, you may have an incompatible version. This thread is specific to a bug in Fedora 16, but may just as well be applicable to your situation. Check the Avalon version and try to down- or upgrade it accordingly.
- [this thread shows](http://gnucash.1415818.n4.nabble.com/Docs-build-failure-java-failure-building-PDF-td3638662.html), quote (half way down):

  > fop-0.95 doesn't work with [avalon-framework-4.3.3](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=704298). Fop 1.x has been fixed in the meantime to work with avalon-framework, but it has another critical bug that prevents the [creation of pdf files](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=689930).

Bottom line of all these threads (and many more) is: the (correct) Avalon is not found. Fix that, and you should solve your issue.

Comment: hi i resolve that issue  but show some error                                       Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xmlgraphics.xmp.Metadata.mergeInto(Lorg/apache/xmlgraphics/xmp/Metadata;)V

Comment: @SenthilKumar, that is a different error, though possibly with a similar cause. In that case, the class was found, but the method was not. This may be cause by an incorrect or incomplete version of that class. Add the correct version and you should be solid, or ask it as a new question. You may also try the [FOP mailing list](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/maillist.html).